# Add php function to all POSTs and REQUESTs variables

Tags: php

I have a very old client who is now having issues with security because of the `MYSQL` Injection. This client does not have enough money to change his PHP database functions to `PDO` or `MYSQLI`. Nevertheless, he suggested that he wants a function that prevents mysql injuction. He is fully aware that the function is not perfect. But, he does not have any other temporary way right now. the function that I wrote for him is called `safe();`. Here comes my question. How can I apply the function to all `POST`s and `REQUEST`s in his site. His site has many files, it will take hours to change. is there anything that I can add in the Header of every file that applies my function to all `POST`s and `REQUEST`s variables?

something that maybe looks like this :

```
$_POST[*] = safe($_POST[*]);
```

Of course, the above code does not work. but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Like `mysql_real_escape_string`?

Comment: Only if you *never, ever* use anything in POST or REQUEST for anything other then being mashed into a string containing an SQL query without prior modification.

Comment: It might be worth your client taking action against whomever their bought the original system from for providing a product that is not fit for purpose.

Comment: @Quentin we are talking about a third-world country client. And a very old system .. probably 10 years ago.. which of course did use mysql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `array_map`, but I doubt it'll be perfect solution:

```
$final = array_map( "mysql_real_escape_string", $_POST );
```

Answer (score 3):

In the end $_POST and $_GET are just arrays.
You could do a foreach like

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
  safe($value);
}
```

if they have old php servers etc. So if you have a general file that is included over the whole website and the "normal" functions aren't an option, this could be the back-up plan.

Comment: Surely ```$$key = safe($value);```?

Answer (score 3):

You are describing the infamous [Magic Quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php), which are still available if the server is older than PHP/5.4.0 (which I presume is the case).

Please note that they affect all POST data, including that which is not going to be injected in a SQL query.

If you prefer your `safe()` function, you can simply write a simple script that makes the change and call it via [auto_prepend_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file).

Answer (score 2):

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664021/php-escaping-vars-posted-through-var-and-got-by-postvari-with-a-meth

As I was told, there's no universal method, but you can give it a try through foreaching the $_POST array

Comment: lol, maybe whoever downvoted me 3 months after the post is made, will care to add a comment :D